# Dataframe filtering with condition applied to list of columns

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I want to filter a pyspark dataframe if any of the string columns in a list are empty.

```
df = df.where(all([col(x)!='' for x in col_list]))

ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` from `functools` to simulate `all` like this

```
from functools import reduce

spark_df.where(reduce(lambda x, y: x & y,  (F.col(x) != '' for x in col_list))).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `filter` (or `where`) are lazy evaluated transformation we can merge multiple conditions by applying them one by one, e.g.

```
for c in col_list:
    spark_df = spark_df.filter(col(c) != "")

spark_df.show()
```

Which may be a bit more readable, but in the end it will be executed in a completely same way as Sreeram's answer.

On a side note, removing rows with empty values would be most often done with

```
df.na.drop(how="any", subset=col_list)
```

but it only handles missing (null / None) values, not empty strings.